# How to get world position of detected Aruco markers with openCv?

Tags: python, opencv, ros, aruco

I am detecting Aruco code with:

```py
rvec, tvec = aruco.estimatePoseSingleMarkers(corners, markersize, cam_mat, dist_coef)
```

what I get are rvec, tvec that are relative to the camera position.

Also i can easily get Word position of detected camera using:

```py
(trans, rot) = listener.lookupTransform('odom', 'base_footprint', rospy.Time(0))
```

So my question is how to calculate the position of the aruco code relative to world positions? My goal is to use MoveBaseGoal() for navigation to this Marker.

I m new to this so I'd like to hear advice on how to do it right

I have calibrated camera for accuracy.

Comment: Can you provide a transformation from camera to world frame?

Comment: @ignacio trans from camera using lookupTransfrom is `[-0.6997662975521766, 0.000662322948262164, -0.0010073995085540174]` which is world position of camera and output from aruco tvec is `[[[ 3.52228065 -2.75790491 59.53842544]]]`

Comment: I don't know if I am missing something, but I think the solution to your question is for you to publish the transformation from `aruco` frame  to the `camera` frame. As you already have the transformation from `camera` to `world` frame, you have the whole chain from `aruco` to `world`